# How do i add a form submission counter?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

so I'm working on a taking a pledge page and I was wondering how can i implement a counter on the page when a user has submitted the form. For instance, 
I want to have it display as this.

[ Thank you for taking your time to take the pledge. So far, 5 people have pledged.]

then if another user submitted the form, then it'll add 1 to the counter.

Thank you all <3

Comment: Do you have a backend?

Answer (score 0):

I think adding some PHP code as follows, on the same page as your javascript/html should work. Just note that this should be above all html.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $counter = isset($_POST['counter']) ? $_POST['counter'] : 0;
    if(isset($_POST["button"])){
        $counter++;
        echo $counter;
    }
}
```

This is essentially a button click counter, so anytime a button is pressed the count will increment. When a form is submitted I'm assuming a button is pressed.